# Dicks–Dunwoody almost stability theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory

In the book 'Groups acting on graphs' (1989), Dicks and Dunwoody prove the following theorem (paraphrased):

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $E$, let $E'$ be a subset of $E$ and let $V$ be the set of all subsets $E''$ of $E$ such that $E'' \triangle E'$ is finite.  Suppose $G$ has finite stabilisers on $E$ and that $G$ preserves the set $V$.  Then $G$ acts on a tree with vertex set $V$ (with the same $G$-action), such that edge stabilisers are finite.

1. It takes about 25 pages until the theorem is proved.  Is there a short(er) known proof nowadays?
2. Suppose $G$ is a closed subgroup of the symmetric group on $E$ with respect to pointwise convergence.  Does the theorem still hold if 'finite (edge) stabilisers' are replaced throughout with 'compact (edge) stabilisers'?  (More generally, I'd also be interested in other versions of this theorem with different kinds of 'small' edge stabilisers.)

Edit re 2: If $G$ has compact open stabilisers on $E$, it looks like we at least get a nice action of $G$ on a CAT(0) cube complex with $0$-skeleton $V$, via a construction of Sageev for pairs of groups with more than one end.  What's not clear is when this reduces to an action on a tree.  Perhaps there are known examples that don't reduce to the tree case, in which case I'm interested in what exactly breaks down in the Dicks–Dunwoody theorem when replacing 'finite' with 'compact'.

Comment: This result includes Stallings' theorem as a corollary, so it's unclear there's a too simple proof (Dunwoody had already simplified and improved Stallings' result). Abels proved in 1974 the locally compact version of Stallings' theorem, but I'm not sure about such a general version.

Comment: I'd guess that the result is true when the stabilizers are compact open, just nobody has tried to check it so far.

Comment: The action on a CAT(0) cube complex with 0-skeleton $V$ and $E$ as set of hyperplanes is essentially tautological, with no assumption on stabilizer (because $V$ already forms the 0-skeleton of an obvious complex).

Comment: Indeed, the translation is very straightforward in hindsight, but there have been a few papers spelling out the CAT(0) cube complex <-> median graph <-> space with walls <-> almost invariant set equivalences, so I didn't want to say it is completely obvious.  Compactness of stabilisers is perhaps a strong enough assumption to get something better.

Comment: There are indeed several papers on how to construct a cubulation out of an commensurating action ("almost invariant set"). There's indeed a "tautological" construction yielding a huge complex, and these paper struggle to get a better construction (typically, finite-dimensional, proper) using stronger hypotheses on the group and action. The first such paper is implicitly Stallings' (finite stabilizers), and later and more explicitly, Sageev (hyperbolic group + quasi-convex stabilizers).